# How to run a NetBeans project in command prompt?

Tags: java, command-line, netbeans

My professor asked us to create a Java program that would be able to run in command prompt but could also be opened using NetBeans.

The program is about using the different types of sorting (specifically Selection, Insertion, Exchange, Quick, and Heap sorting). our professor specifically told us to use object oriented programming in Java, and that she wants to see a main class plus the different classes that would do the sorting.

I tried to write the program in NetBeans — thinking that later I could simply run the program in cmd using javac.

In cmd, I typed the path where my NetBeans project was saved and I tried to compile the files using javac. but it says that "'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

So I tried to save the files in sun>sdk>jdk>bin, and from there I tried to compile the files, and it was fine. The problem sets in when I tried to run them.

Here's how I tried to compile the files:

```
javac Main.java
      Sortchoice.java
      Selection.java
      SelectionSort.java
      Insertion.java
      InsertionSort.java
      Exchange.java
      ExchangeSort.java
```

(I havent finished the syntax for the next two sorting.)

Here's how I tried to run the files in cmd:

```
java Main Sortchoice Selection SelectionSort Insertion InsertionSort Exchange ExchangeSort
```

and cmd says:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main (wring name: myjava/Main)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Nativ... Method)"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassL...
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineCl...
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLC...
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLCl...
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLo...
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivile... Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLCla...
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoa...
at sun.misc.Launcher&AppClassLoader.loadCla...
at java.lang.ClasLoader.loadClass(ClassLoad...
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(...
```

What should I do? (Sorry for my kilometric-long explanation. I just wanted to put in as many details as possible.)

I would also like to emphasize that I'm just a beginner in Java programming.

Answer (score 24):

If you click build inside NetBeans, it should give you (in your compiler output) a message like, "To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar yourPathToRun"

Answer (score 14):

The best way to do it is this:

1) create a directory with `src\` and `tests\` in it (the tests is optional if you are not using JUnit).

2) assuming you have `package myjava;` at the top of your files (and make sure that this is what your prof wants, it becomes a pain to mark things if they are not in the right place), make a `src\myjava` directory (and if you are doing JUnit a `tests\myjava` directory).

3) copy your files into the `src\myjava` directory

4) delete your NetBeans project and recreate it as a new on with exising sources.  When you are setting up the `src` (and optional `test`) directories add the `src\` (and optionally the `tests\`) directory.  DO NOT add the `src\myjava` directory or it won't work in NetBeans.

5) make a directory called `classes\` (so you you have `src\`, `classes\`, and maybe `\tests` all in the same place)

6) on the command line type `javac -d classes -cp classes  src/myjava/*.java`

- `-d` tells the compiler where to put the .class files
- `-cp` tells the compiler where to look for classfiles
- `src/myjava/*.java` tells it to compile all of the .java files in `src/myjava`

7) run it via `java -cp classes myjava.Main`

- `-cp` classes tells it to look in the classes directory for the .class files
- `myjava.Main` is the name of the class to run

Answer (score 6):

1. It would be better to add javac to your PATH environment variable instead of putting the .java files into the same directory with it. It'll get awfully crowded in there.
2. To run, you just need

   > `java Main`

   instead of putting every class on the command line.
3. Did you declare a package in your .java files? Like,

   > package myjava;

   ? If so, the command string must be

   > `java myjava.Main`

Does that answer your questions?

Answer (score 2):

Right click My Computer>properties>advanced>environment variables...add the bin directory in jdk to the Path variable
example:
Variable Name: path
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin

java and javac should now work from any directory in the command prompt

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to run the `.jar` file in the `dist` folder under your project's main folder. Make sure the path to the jdk `bin` folder in your computer's `System`, `Environmental Variables` is set to find the usual: `jar.exe`, `java.exe`, `javac.exe`, etc, (see other posts in this thread if you need instructions on doing that).

1) In Netbeans do a clean build, press `F11` or click on the `Run` menu and click on `Build Project`. Click through to get past all the prompts, you need a clean build to do this.

2) in the command prompt navigate to your project's `dist` folder

3) on the command line type in and run: `java -jar yourMainFile.jar`

No creating separate folders, no copying files, no multiple files to include on the command line argument. But you will have to re-build your project each time you change your code before running it on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps (code examples are just examples, you will need to tweak some for your setup):

1. Set your JAVA_HOME to the directory where the JDK is installed.

   set JAVA_HOME="c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_12"
2. Set your PATH to include the `bin` directory in JAVA_HOME.

   set PATH=%PATH%:%JAVA_HOME%\bin
3. Change to the root directory of your source code.  If you have declared your code to be in packages, this is the root directory of your package structure.  If not, this is the directory that contains your .java files:

   cd c:\My\Source\Directory
4. Execute javac with your Java files as the argument:

   javac Class1.java Class2.java
5. (Assuming everything compiles correctly) Execute `java` with the name of the class containing your main method as the argument (if you included package declarations, then your class name is fully-qualified, meaning it should include the package name before the class name, with a '.' separating the package name from the class name):

   java Main

Comment: As Java Home's use may conflict with other tools, I'd recommend setting the JRE into the path directly rather than using Java Home.  For instance, that Java home won't work with Maven, because it assumes Java Home is the JDK root path...

Comment: If you don't set JAVA_HOME in the control panel, but just in your local shell, it won't effect anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder somewhere, say `C:\myjava`. Copy your `.java` source files from wherever netbeans saves them to your `C:\java` for example. Open each of these `.java` files you have just pasted and delete the line that states the package e.g `package myjava`. Compile using `javac` e.g. `javac c:\myjava\MyJava.java`. Then run it as in, java `c:\myjava\MyJava`

Answer (score 0):

You will have a **build** directory inside your project. Navigate to it. Next open the **classes** folder. 
Now here open the terminal and run `java x/y`

 **where** x is the name of the package your main class is in and y is the name of that java file

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the package line in your class.java file.