# Is there a console profiler for Java?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, console, profiling

Is there a gprof-like profiler for Java that can be run from the terminal in Linux?
All tools I have found are GUI programs and I need run it from the terminal.

Answer (score 11):

The JVM has a built-in profiler called [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html).  You can enable it on the command line like this:

```
java -agentlib:hprof=file=hprof.txt,cpu=samples MyClass
```

This will dump profile information out to a text file when the program finishes.  In addition to profiling CPU usage, it can also track heap usage.

Comment: it profiling every class, or can it profile everything in my program

Comment: It profiles every class.  It will dump truncated stack traces that are useful to find out where slow calls originate from in your program.  You can control how big the stacktraces are with the `depth` option.

Comment: Could not find the main class: Prime.java. Program will exit. {but I set  main class}

Comment: Edited answer: -agentlib should appear before the name of the class to be run.

Comment: You need to pass `java` the name of your class (`Prime`) without `.java` at the end.  Make sure you've compiled it with `javac` first.

Comment: it gives me error " Dumping CPU usage by sampling running threads ... done.
Could not find the main class: Prime. Program will exit."

Comment: i run it in netbeans , but i need now to run it in terminal and profile it ,, i compiled by javac

Comment: Ok, first get your program running in a terminal with `java` without profiling.  This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626940/how-to-run-a-netbeans-project-in-command-prompt

Comment: Reading this .txt file may be tricky, but JPerfAnal tool helps: `java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel -jar $HOME/Downloads/jperfanal.jar java.hprof.txt` 
Also, option `...,depth=99` for hprof makes it to add full stack traces (for determining who generated that slow method call).

Answer (score 8):

The open-source tool [jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop/) contains a terminal profiler and might be worth a look:

```
JvmTop 0.7.0 alpha - 15:16:34,  amd64,  8 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-27, load avg 0.41
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

 Profiling PID 24015: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

  36.16% (    57.57s) hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calcChangeSet()
  30.36% (    48.33s) hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser.parse()
   7.14% (    11.37s) org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.parseScript()
   6.25% (     9.95s) net.sf.json.JSONObject.write()
   3.13% (     4.98s) ....kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CustomTagLibrary.loadJellyScri()
```

Comment: Just to add, this output requires the `--profile <pid>` option

Comment: Future Readers: On JDK 9+ this will not work since **`$JAVA_HOME/lib.tools.jar`** is needed by *`jvmtop`*, even manually installing it won't work so don't attemp to do so!

Answer (score 3):

JXInsight/OpenCore has term/shell reporting plugins (top, queues, stacks,...) that will output its metering and metrics data at regular intervals. It is also possible to access this information using the Open API which allows inspection of the model in real-time within the JVM or offline using a snapshot file handle. Both are supported via Plugin API which it how the top, queues,... ones work.

http://www.jinspired.com/products/opencore (commercial)

Is there a technical reason you can't use a GUI? Is it just a preference driven by a workflow habit? If not then you can always try out our FREE JXInsight/Opus Java Edition - a highly efficient and scalable code level latency performance measurement solution for rapidly identifying hotspots within Java and JRuby applications.

http://www.jinspired.com/products/opus

Note: I am the product architect of both products.

Answer (score 2):

I use jconsole for that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jconsole.html

Comment: I couldn't find how to install it

Comment: It comes with the JDK itself... It's a command, just like javac/java.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it for profiling and monitoring. You can use [Jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).

from App site:

**DESCRIPTION**
Java VisualVM is an intuitive graphical user interface that provides detailed information about Java technology-based applications (Java applications) while they are running on a given Java Virtual Machine (JVM*). The name Java VisualVM comes from the fact that Java VisualVM provides information about the JVM software visually.

Java VisualVM combines several monitoring, troubleshooting, and profiling utilities into a single tool. For example, most of the functionality offered by the standalone tools jmap, jinfo, jstat and jstack have been integrated into Java VisualVM. Other functionalities, such as some of those offered by the JConsole tool, can be added as optional plug-ins.

**EDIT:**
As you want a terminal approach.Refer this link [Triggering a Javadump](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/tools/javadump_trigger.html).
It describes creation of java dump.

Comment: I thought jvisualvm was a GUI application.  Can it be run in terminal mode?

Comment: Its a GUI App. But you can connect to our linux server by specifing the remote server IP and port.